# How to handle button event of ListView of Fragment class?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I have used `Fragment` in my code. i have to display custom `ListView` in fragment. But I would like to handle `Button`'s `onClickListener` event which is in this `ListView`.
How to use these `Button` components in `Fragment` class? Because `ListView`'s row layout is another layout I can use it in the `Fragment` class.
Here is my code:
**My fragmnent class**

```
public class VoteFragment extends Fragment
{
    ListView list_model;
    View rootView;
    private String models_name[]={"MehararPaurKamali", "Elmira Panajavi","Hanay YavariMoghadam","MehararPaurKamali"};
    private String models_adress[]={"Icon Girmfriend", "Deccan","ShivajiNagar","India"};
    int model_images[]={R.drawable.karina,R.drawable.karina,R.drawable.karina,R.drawable.karina};
    ArrayList<ModelListItem> modelList;
    ModelListItem modelItem;
    Button btn_home_model_plus;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {   
        modelList=new ArrayList<ModelListItem>();
        for(int i=0;i<models_name.length;i++)
        {   modelItem=new ModelListItem();
        modelItem.setModelname(models_name[i]);
        modelItem.setModelAdress(models_adress[i]);
        modelItem.setModel_image(model_images[i]);
        modelList.add(modelItem);

        }   

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_vote,container, false);
        setUI();
        //Public void myClickHandler(){}
        return rootView;
    }
    private void setUI() 
    {
        list_model=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_home_model);
        btn_home_model_plus=(Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_home_model_plus);

    }


}
```

**Adapter class is**

```
public class HomeModelListAdapter extends BaseAdapter  implements OnClickListener
{

    private ArrayList<ModelListItem> modelList;
    private Context context;
    Button btn_home_model_plus,btn_home_model_vote;
    FragmentManager fragmentmanager;

    public HomeModelListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ModelListItem> modelList) 
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.modelList=modelList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return modelList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) 
    {
        return modelList.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) 
    {
        return arg0;
    }
    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder 
    {   
        ImageView imgModelimage;
        TextView txtModeName;
        TextView txtModelAdress;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2)
    {  ViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) 
    {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fram_home_list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtModeName= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_home_model_name);
        holder.txtModelAdress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_home_model_adress);
        holder.imgModelimage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_home_model);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    holder.txtModeName.setText(modelList.get(position).getModelname());
    holder.txtModelAdress.setText(modelList.get(position).getModelAdress());
    holder.imgModelimage.setImageResource(modelList.get(position).getModel_image());
    btn_home_model_plus=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_home_model_plus);
    btn_home_model_vote=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_home_model_vote);

    btn_home_model_plus.setOnClickListener(this);


    return convertView;


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {  Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (v.getId()) 
        {
        case R.id.btn_home_model_plus:
             System.out.println("Hi.................");
            fragment = new ModelProfileDetailFragment();

            break;
        case R.id.btn_home_model_vote:

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        if (fragment != null)
        {   
            fragmentmanager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fram_home, fragment).commit();
            //notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

**Listview row Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:padding="@dimen/s5dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_image_layout"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_home_model"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/karina" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/s10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rel_right_layout"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rel_image_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_home_model_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight="35"
            android:fontFamily="Roboto"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="Mehrara Pourkamli"
            android:textColor="#606366"
            android:textSize="@dimen/s17sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_home_model_adress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="35"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/pointer"
            android:fontFamily="Roboto"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="    Richmond Hill, ON"
            android:textColor="#898e91"
            android:textSize="@dimen/s12sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel_right_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="30" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_home_model"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="#ca1b76"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:padding="@dimen/s5dp"
                android:text="Vote Now"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_right_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_home_model_plus"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_plus"
            android:onClick="myClickHandler"
            android:padding="@dimen/s5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please give me suggestion.

Comment: have click listener for button in getView of Custom adapter

Comment: How can i take click llistner in  Adapter Class? I have  use btn_home_model_plus=(Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_home_model_plus); for taking Button View .But when i handle its click listener its give nullpointer exception.

Comment: @ Raghunandan Sir,Please see below code.

Comment: Raghunandan Sir,I got one problem How to create fragmentManager class for inflating fragment.Plz give me suggestion

Comment: i have edited your answer please delete the code posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right I think your problem is quite simple. All you need to do is edit your `HomeModelListAdapter`'s `getView()` method class like this.

```
public class HomeModelListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    .....
    .....
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2)
    {
        .....
        btn_home_model_plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do your stuff here
            }
        });
        btn_home_model_vote.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do your stuff here
            }
        });
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

Hopefully this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to access your fragment manager
((Activity) context).getFragmentManager();

I want to know how your list view is linked with your fragment.

Comment: Please use edits/comments to work on your existing answer instead of posting a new one.

Comment: Sandhip, i'm removing the old answer as it wont be needed for you.